# Install PEAR2 / pyrus.phar on PH 7.0.8 throw PyrusXMLParserException: Invalid XML document

Tags: pear, php-7, pyrus

I am new here. My first question / request is about PEAR2 / pyrus.phar.

I get an exception on this command (when I type it on the Command Prompt):

```
php pyrus.phar
```

Exception:

> PyrusXMLParserException: Invalid XML document PyrusXMLParserException:
>   Line 2: Element
>   '{http://pear2.php.net/dtd/customcommand-2.0}commands', attribute
>   'version': The value '(null)' does not match the fixed value
>   constraint '2.0'.

My Configuration:

> Windows 10 PHP 7.0.8

If I use PHP 7.0.2 it works for me. After many trials I figured out that these two files involved in it:

- php7.dll Non Thread Safe
- php7ts.dll Thread Safe

If I replace the `php7.dll` from PHP 7.0.8 with the file from PHP 7.0.2 or the `php7ts.dll` from PHP 7.0.8 with the file from PHP 7.0.2 it works.

Thank you for your effort.

Best regards

rikku47

PS: If you need more information, just ask. I do not know, what is important too.

Additonal:

PEAR Version 1.10.1 achieved with the command: `pear version` on the Command Prompt.

PEAR2 / pyrus.phar Version 2.0.0a4 achieved with the command: `pyrus.phar` on the Command Prompt. Yes here it works with the installation with PHP 7.0.2. [link](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/php-7.0.2-nts-Win32-VC14-x86.zip)

It works with PHP 7.0.7 too.

Update: After a reinstall of Windows 10 it happens again.

Comment: What is your PEAR version number ?

Comment: The version of PEAR is 1.10.1. Have used the command: pear version

Comment: And the version of PEAR2 / pyrus.phar is 2.0.0a4. Got this from the installation from PHP version 7.0.2. from this URL [link](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/php-7.0.2-nts-Win32-VC14-x86.zip)